# MVC scroll windows disappear when Bootstrap modal popup window close

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

I have an `MVC` with `Bootstrap` App.

I have a `JavaScript` function that open a `Bootstrap Modal PopUp` Windows.

```html
 function AnwComment()
        {
            $('#myModalComment').modal({ backdrop: "static" });
        }
```

My  when I load `partial View` is like this.

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalComment" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/UploadSearch/_Comment.cshtml");
</div>
```

When I submit `partial view` I call a `JavaScript` function where I force to close the Windows.

```html
function SaveComment() {
 $("#closeComm_btn").trigger("click");
 // LoadComment();
}
```

My partial view is simple. It has two buttoms, "Close" and "Save".

Everithing Works fine... but strange things happens when I call another `JavaScript` function called `LoadComment();`

That function returns a Partial View that it is  render on a `<div>`

```html
 function LoadComment() {
        $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("GetUploadComment", "UploadSearch")',
                    data: { Upload_id: $("#Upload_id").val() },
                    success: function (result) {
                        $('#DvComments').html(result);
                    },
                    error: function (req, status, error) {
                                               }
                });
    }
```

That Method render the Partial View in a `div`. As the main View is large, I have scroll Windows by default, but srcoll disappear when partial view renders an i can not reach the top of the page.

How can I refresh a Partial View without losing scroll window?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It i solved [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28643617/bootstrap-modal-makes-scrollbar-disappear-after-closing)

using

> $('body').removeClass('modal-open');