# Multiple Bootstrap modals scrolling issue

Tags: css, bootstrap-modal

Originally, there was only one modal on the site. It was working with the scrollbar but having the main page locked (there was only one scrollbar showed, the modal one).

Then, I added a second modal (really don't like multiple modals but not my choice here), same behaviour: main page and first modal are locked, only scrolling for the new modal.

But when closing this new modal, two scrollbars appears, one for the original modal and an outer one for the main page.

I want this to work as it was without the second modal: when I close the second modal, I want only the first modal scrollbar to show, instead of the double scrollbar.

Already tried playing with the CSS but can't achieve it, and tried some answers about similar questions here but didn't work either.

**Edit 1:**
I checked this in the [get Bootstrap site](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#scrolling-long-content) and I'm getting the same result. When opening any modal the scroll is locked for the modal only. But then, I opened a second modal (via jQuery in console) and closed it. Now only one scrollbar is showed and it's for the main page, the first modal it's not scrollable anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a modal is opened, `modal-open` class is added to the body. And when a modal is closed, that class is removed. So, when I close the second modal, that class is removed, showing the scroll from the main page.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28907348/2051332) I found the solution: To add a call to a method when the second modal is closed, calling this line `$('body').addClass('modal-open');`. That way, we still have the needed CSS when closing the second modal.

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('body').addClass('modal-open');
})
```