# Modal button changes position when clicked

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm working on a website, you can view the [website here.](http://www.fantasylab.no/comingsoon)

**Issue:**
When you click the "Bestill nå" button at the top right corner, you can see that the positioning of the button changes when clicked.

How can I make it so that the positioning is the same when the button is clicked?

Here is the full header HTML:

```
    <header id="hjem">

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation" id="navbar">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" rel="Hjem" href="#hjem" title="FantasyLab">
                    <img src="images/fantasylab-logo.svg" style="width: 160px;">
                    </a>
                </div> <!-- navbar-header -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
                        <li><a class="se1" href="#om-fantasylab">Om Fantasylab</a></li>
                        <li><a class="se2" href="#referanser">Referanser</a></li>
                        <li><a class="se3" href="#lansering">Lansering</a></li>
                        <li><a class="se4" href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a></li>
                    </ul>
                    <div class="social pull-right" style="margin: 13px 140px 0 0">

                        <a href="https://www.facebook.com/pages/FantasyLab/678021948955247?ref=bookmarks" target="_blank"><img class="facebook" src='images/social-sprite.svg' alt='Icons'></a>
                        <a href="https://twitter.com/FantasyLabNorge" target="_blank"><img class="twitter" src='images/social-sprite.svg' alt='Icons'></a> 
                        <a href="https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC3SHLhbbBcWzanTm-vzrIyQ" target="_blank"><img class="youtube" src='images/social-sprite.svg' alt='Icons'></a> 
                        <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/fantasylab-norway" target="_blank"><img class="linkedin" src='images/social-sprite.svg' alt='Icons'></a> 
                        <a href="https://plus.google.com/110982605350769996479/posts" target="_blank"><img class="google-plus" src='images/social-sprite.svg' alt='Icons'></a>
                    </div> 
        </div> <!-- navbar-collapse -->
            </div> <!-- container -->
              <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
              <div class="container">
              <button type="button" class="header-button btn btn-default navbar-btn pull-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Bestill nå</button>

              <!-- Modal -->
              <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">

                  <!-- Modal content-->
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                      <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                      <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
              </div>
        </nav> 
    </header> <!-- header -->
```

CSS I have added for the modal function:

```
.modal-backdrop {
position: relative !important;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

**EDIT:**
After adding this CSS:

```
body.modal-open {
 overflow: auto;
 padding-right: 0 !important;

}
```

It fixed the problem. However the `padding-right:` is coming from `element.style` on `class="modal-open"` which has a default `padding-right: 17px;`. I believe this gets added to the body by jQuery. Does anyone know how I can remove this from the jQuery instead of adding it in the CSS?

jQuery code for the modal button:

```
(function($){

// Defining our jQuery plugin

$.fn.paulund_modal_box = function(prop){

    // Default parameters

    var options = $.extend({
        height : "250",
        width : "500",
        title:"JQuery Modal Box Demo",
        description: "Example of how to create a modal box.",
        top: "20%",
        left: "30%",
    },prop);

    //Click event on element
    return this.click(function(e){
        add_block_page();
        add_popup_box();
        add_styles();

        $('.paulund_modal_box').fadeIn();
    });

    /**
     * Add styles to the html markup
     */
     function add_styles(){         
        $('.paulund_modal_box').css({ 
            'position':'absolute', 
            'left':options.left,
            'top':options.top,
            'display':'none',
            'height': options.height + 'px',
            'width': options.width + 'px',
            'border':'1px solid #fff',
            'box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
            '-moz-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
            '-webkit-box-shadow': '0px 2px 7px #292929',
            'border-radius':'10px',
            '-moz-border-radius':'10px',
            '-webkit-border-radius':'10px',
            'background': '#f2f2f2', 
            'z-index':'50',
        });
        $('.paulund_modal_close').css({
            'position':'relative',
            'top':'-25px',
            'left':'20px',
            'float':'right',
            'display':'block',
            'height':'50px',
            'width':'50px',
            'background': 'url(images/close.png) no-repeat',
        });
        $('.paulund_block_page').css({
            'position':'absolute',
            'top':'0',
            'left':'0',
            'background-color':'rgba(0,0,0,0.6)',
            'height':'100%',
            'width':'100%',
            'z-index':'10'
        });
        $('.paulund_inner_modal_box').css({
            'background-color':'#fff',
            'height':(options.height - 50) + 'px',
            'width':(options.width - 50) + 'px',
            'padding':'10px',
            'margin':'15px',
            'border-radius':'10px',
            '-moz-border-radius':'10px',
            '-webkit-border-radius':'10px'
        });
    }

     /**
      * Create the block page div
      */
     function add_block_page(){
        var block_page = $('<div class="paulund_block_page"></div>');

        $(block_page).appendTo('body');
    }

     /**
      * Creates the modal box
      */
     function add_popup_box(){
         var pop_up = $('<div class="paulund_modal_box"><a href="#" class="paulund_modal_close"></a><div class="paulund_inner_modal_box"><h2>' + options.title + '</h2><p>' + options.description + '</p></div></div>');
         $(pop_up).appendTo('.paulund_block_page');

         $('.paulund_modal_close').click(function(){
            $(this).parent().fadeOut().remove();
            $('.paulund_block_page').fadeOut().remove();                 
         });
    }

    return this;
};

})(jQuery);
```

Comment: It is not showing any modal to me, it is sending me to a contact form.

Comment: sorry, didn't update code, try again.

Comment: possible duplicate of [bootstrap modal removes scroll bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070144/bootstrap-modal-removes-scroll-bar)

Comment: Absolutely. The dissapearing scrollbar is making that button to move. Also I recommend adding `width: 100%;` to the `class="img-responsive"` because right now it is not covering the full width.

Comment: I see, is there any way I can fix it without adding a scrollbar to the modal? Also thanks for noticing the `class="img-responsive"` i've added the `width: 100%;` now.

Comment: @DerekS I tried to add the CSS `.modal-open {
    overflow: scroll;}` from the link you added, but that made the body move instead.