# Bootstrap open-modal scroll issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am having a problem when I open a Bootstrap modal, it sort of moves the entire website a bit. I checked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070144/bootstrap-modal-removes-scroll-bar) out, but adding `.modal-open { overflow: scroll }` did not help me, as yes, it made it keep the right side scroll bar, but the problem was not that it disapeared, just that it moved the whole website a little to the right - this also resulted in a bottom scrollbar, affecting the footer.

I am basically just looking for a conclusion where triggering a Bootstrap modal does not move my entire website, this gif demonstrates it;
[image]

I have not added other custom css affecting the `.modal-open` other than `overflow: scroll`. Although I have tried setting it to `overflow: auto` and hidden ect., nothing really helped.

Comment: when modal open, it push the website 15px left because created an invisible scroll so page behind modal will be scroll-able.

Comment: the issue you demonstrate in the gif doesn't has any thing to do with `.modal-open`

Comment: @Shehary well I don't know what it is then...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like problem with overlay - can you check out it's styles?

Comment: I have not added any custom CSS with the propperty `overlay`

Comment: So maybe you should :P