# Modal Js to Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some simple modal. Its in js,  but i need to move this to Jquery and have problem with that. Can you please help me? Here is [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xLfnwg5o/) if needed. Also is there a way to remove scrolling if height is set to 100%?

```js
const modal = document.getElementById("myModal");
const btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
const span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
btn.onclick = function () {
  modal.style.display = "block";
};
span.onclick = function () {
  modal.style.display = "none";
};
window.onclick = function (event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
};
```

```css
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}

.modal-content {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-top: 2%;
}

.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
 <div id="myModal" class="modal">     
      <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>Some text </p>
      </div>    
    </div>
            <button  class = "" id="myBtn">Full ingridients</button>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/328193)  If you're asking how to use jQuery or any specific jQuery plugin(s) then your best bet would be to start with some introductory tutorials on those.  You are encouraged to make an attempt.  If during that attempt you encounter a specific problem such as an error or unexpected result, we can help with that.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use .on() function with ID and Class selectors. Please refer to remove scrolling [bootstrap modal removes scroll bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25070144/bootstrap-modal-removes-scroll-bar)

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myBtn').on('click', function () {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
        $('#myModal').css('display', 'block');
    });

    $('.close').on('click', function () {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
    });
});
```