# Remove vertical scrollbar in bootstrap modal popup

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap modal popup on my page. The popup is a bit long so html adds the vertical scroll bar which doesn't look so good with the animation effect.

[image]
So, I want to remove this scroll bar but still be able to scroll.

Any help?

Comment: You know what? screenshot not enough, provide live demo

Comment: Browser compatible answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47807685/7186739

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may help you. Fixing the overflow hidden will remove the scrollbar, To get full content within the page use overflow auto to modal body

CSS:

```
  .modal{
    overflow:hidden;
    }
    .modal-body{
    overflow:auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using bootstrap version 4. You can use this css code.

```
.modal-scrollbar-measure {
overflow: hidden !Important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

`.modal` class has `overflow-y: scroll` rule which results in scrollbar always visible.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18715220/9143855

Answer (score 0):

that because you use overflow : scroll ;
the scroll value of overflow property add scroll ball line to both sides vertically and horizontally you should use instead overflow auto which will just add one side scroll for which it needed the most

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the modal events for this:

```
$("#modalID").on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    /* Hide the body scrollbar. */
    document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
});

$("#modalID").on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
    /* Show the body scrollbar. */
    document.body.style.overflow = "auto";
});
```

the events can be seen here: https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/modals/events/