# How to remove vertical scrolling on data table bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4

I'm fetching some data using while loop from the database but 
When I have a lot of entries in my data table  this scrollbar shows up :

[screen shot](http://prntscr.com/iyl55s)

what I have tried :

```
#mytable::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}
```

and :

```
.table .table-bordered .table-striped  {

    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

I'm using bootstrap 3 template

my code :

```
<table id="rip"class="table table-bordered table-striped js-dataTable-full-pagination">

<thead>

<tr>
<th><input id="selectAllboxes" type="checkbox">

<th>cc num</th>
<th>cc</th>
<th>student name</th>
<th>com date</th>
<th>stats</th>
<th>Edit</th>
<th>Print</th>


</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>




   echo "<tr>";
   ?>
  <th><input class='checkboxes' type='checkbox' name='checkBoxArray[]' value='<?php echo $cert_id; ?>'></th>

   <?php
   echo "<td>{$cert_id}</td>";
   echo "<td>{$course_title}</td>";
   echo "<td>{$name_student}</td>";
   echo "<td>{$date_com}</td>";
 echo "<td>$status</td>";

echo"<td>

<a  href='' target='_blank'><i class='fa fa-print fa-2x'></i></a></a>
</td>




";

echo "<td><a href=''><i class='fa fa-edit fa-2x'></i></a></td>";

echo "</tr>";
      }
?>

</tbody>
</table>
```

from what I have tried nothing worked so far.

Any idea how I can remove the scrollbar?

Comment: Can you include your code?

Comment: @JonathanChaplin I've included the code

Answer (score 0):

In your css try adding :

```
    body {
        overflow-y:hidden;
    }
```

As suggested by [Bootstrap : how to disable vertical scrollbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17726641/bootstrap-how-to-disable-vertical-scrollbar)

Answer (score 0):

Solved by adding 
scrollY : False;

to js file